Error: Class 'App:User' is not defined for SQL Query
I'm trying to run my old script in Symfony 7. I get the message

Error: Class 'App:User' is not defined

for my SQL query.
When I change App:User to App\Entity\User in the SQL query, everything works. How can I make the App:User definition work as well?

App:User is what is known as an alias in which App is mapped to the App\Entity namespace. It is no longer used by default. I suppose you could dig into the documentation to figure out how to add it back. But your best bet is just update your queries. Might be a pain but it really is the best approach going forward.

For example, the following looks for entity classes in the Entity namespace in the src/Entity directory and gives them an App alias (so you can say things like App:Post):
doctrine:
        # ...
        orm:
            # ...
            mappings:
                # ...
                SomeEntityNamespace:
                    type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    is_bundle: false
                    prefix: App\Entity
                    alias: App

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle

It is set this way in the doctrine.yaml file by default, but the App alias does not work.
